# Is it possible to mirror a log-In popup window of a web-App using react Native for a mobile App?

Tags: database, react-native, mobile, server, simulation

Is it possible to build a React Native App with a log-In screen that simulate/mirror a popup window of web-App having in mind that we don't have access neither to the server nor to the database of this web-app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer will be no, while this might technically possible.

You can of course mirror everything an already implemented login does, from the client side, including the HTTP requests to the server but usually that is very uncommon.

What someone usually does is

- either use an existing pattern to talk to a backend service
- or implement one (also on the backend side)

In general, you do not want to have any security features implemented in the frontend as it can be manipulated.

Comment: I am aware of issue but i have no other option. could you please tell me more in details how to achieve the mirroring process?

Comment: Well, the reason why I did not was: it depends a lot on how it is implemented. In very general Terms, check wich HTML and js parts are used, copy them and maybe change some ids so that the two versions do not conflict. It could be as simple as including a certain js file, or it could be that you have to orchestrate a whole bunch of different code/stuff in the right way. without more information, someone can not help you.